# How to use THREE js TextureLoader() in React native?

Tags: react-native, 3d, three.js

I am trying to create a 3D model in React-Native using Three.js, for that I have to use an image for texture but TextureLoader() function using 'document' and 'canvas' object creation logic, which can't be used in react-native.

so, how can I use an image as texture in react-native using three.js ?

Comment: I have exactly the same question! Any solutions?

Comment: @robertjuh, no luck... still searching for a solution :(

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to override document.createElementNS with a custom function so that it will create an Image another way. As far as i know the Textureloader uses the ImageLoader in which the  document.createElementNS function is used.

I will create an answer if i manage to make this work

Comment: @robertjuh, that's great... waiting for the answer :)

Comment: Yea well i managed to override the document.createElementNS function but nothing good came out of it really. The IMG file react native creates appears to be different than the HTML IMG object. Going to speak to another developer about this soon.

Comment: editted my 'answer' a bit but it still doesnt work... I'm going to take a look if headless-gl library can offer a solution

Comment: i found a working solution, see editted answer:

Answer (score 1):

Short summary: the Textureloader didnt work because it required an imageloader which required the inaccesible DOM.

Apparantly there's a THREE.Texture function which i used like this:

```
let texture = new THREE.Texture(
     url //URL = a base 64 JPEG string in this case     
     );

var img = new Image(128, 128);
img.src = url;
texture.normal = img;
```

As you can see i used an Image constructor, this is from React Native and is imported like this:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
```

In the  [react native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) it will explain how it can be used, it supports base64 encoded JPEG.

and finally map the texture to the material:

```
material.map = texture;
```

*Note: i havent tried to show the end result in my webglview yet, but in the element inspector it seems to show proper THREEjs objects.*

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this is not the answer)

EDIT: made the code a bit shorter and use DOMParser, still doesnt work because:
"image.addEventListener is not a function"
Which implies the image object which is created in this method doesnt seem to be able to be used in THREEjs,..

```
var DOMParser = require('react-native-html-parser').DOMParser;
var myDomParser = new DOMParser();
window.document = {};

window.document.createElementNS = (x,y) => {
    if (y === "img") {
        let doc = myDomParser.parseFromString("<html><head></head><body><img class='image' src=''></img></body></html>");
        return doc.getElementsByAttribute("class", "image")[0];
    }
}
```

Edit: be careful with this, because it also overrides the other createElemensNS variants in which they create canvas or other things.